# C++ string std::out_of_range: basic_string::substr

Tags: c++, string, substr

I am making a program with a function that checks for the adjacent characters of a string in an array. I do this with the substring function (among other things), but I need a way to use an if statement to avoid empty strings, like finding the trailing character of the first character in a string. I am new to using strings instead of `char[]`. I want some that essentially does this:

```cpp
if (!Empty ( strings[1].substr(0-1,0) )) {
     std::cout<<"char to left of substr(0)="<<strings[1].substr(0-1,0);
}
```

When I try to reference a non existent char, I get the runtime error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range:
basic_string::substr
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: why did you wrote `0-1`?

Comment: for any string or array element [-1] is supposed to be out of range.

Comment: `char to left of substr(0)=` doesn't make sense. `0` is the very first position in the string.

Comment: *"trailing character of the first character in a string"* I get a feeling you want the last character of the previous string in the array. Is that so? Becasue there's nothing "to the left" of string's first character. *hic sunt leones*

Comment: My point is that my program tries to call the -1th member of the first string when. Is there any way for me to stop it from trying to do this?

Comment: @bakman329: unless your program became self evolving... sure.. don't write silly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, a substring starting at index -1, of length 0.

Or, since the first argument is unsigned, it starts at `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Anyway.

Comment: I want to make an if statement that stops the program from trying to reference a non existent character by seeing if the referenced character is possible

Comment: A) verify the arguments B) catch the exception.

Comment: @bakman329 Then write an if statement that compares the index against `strings[1].size()`, or something similar, instead of this silliness. Alf: Nitpick, `size_t` should be `string::size_type` (I know they're most probably the same type)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm using a few if statements to check if the referenced characters are out of range, but is there any way to check how many cells of data there is in an array, to see if the reference string exceeds that number?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Nevermind. Suggestion A worked for me(B blocks all arguements, not just the invalid ones).

Comment: @bakman329 Please don't write `(closed)` in the question title. Click the green checkmark since Alf solved your problem.